# How to use a Python virtual env in my Ubuntu bash?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I am trying to package my project with a virtual env so that it is easier to implement.

I am trying to do this in a Ubuntu bash.

I have succesfully created a Python venv using the Python `virtualenv` library.

I do manage to activate it using `source venv_name/bin/activate`.
I can indeed see `(venv_name)` at the beginning of my command line.

However, I do not manage to actually use this virtual environment.

I have for proof that when I type `which python3` I get my root python3; and I have tried to update a package in the `virtualenv` but it has been updated in the root python.

What should I do to actually use my virtual env ? For now I am trying:

`python3 myscript.py`

And it is working but I suspect it's running with my root python3.

Comment: Do you also have Python2 installed system-wide? When creating your `virtualenv`, do you pass the `--python=python3` flag for the correct interpreter ?

Comment: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` use this to check which python path it showing system one or virtual one.this will show you that whether your are upgradiing the package from virtual environmne itef or from the global environment. run this script where you run the python script.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two versions of python (2 and 3). You create virtualenv with python 2. Recreate virtualenv with correct python version

Comment: To create a virtualenv with a different python version: `virtualenv --python=python3 venv`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how would I know this is right? I.e. how would I know I am actually using the virtual env ? When I type `which python` in the venv (and not `which python3`) I get the root python...

Comment: For example, I have both versions of python. `which python` return root python 2 version. I create new virtualenv `virtualenv --python=python3 venv` and activate it `source venv/bin/activate`. And when I type `which python` I get venv python 3 version. Works correct for me in Ubutnu 18.04. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make next steps to use python3 virtual environment in Ubutnu:
 1. Install virtual environment lib for python3 with command:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

2. Create your virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

3. Activate it:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Works correct for me in Ubutnu 16.04